# Jquery offset property unreadable error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset

I'm using JavaScript and jQuery to create a horizontal scrolling iframe document using absolute positions for the iframes to make them appear side by side. I'm using a short script based of a jsFiddle I found that displays the co-ords of an element in the top left of the screen and they change as the page is scrolled. I have created my own implementation of this and tried to get it working, but I'm getting an error when I load the site telling me that the top property of an undefined variable cannot be read, even though the first thing I'm doing is defining it. I've looked at all of my code and I can't see why this would be the case, I've got the right jQuery scripts added and I'm defining the variable before it's being used as is the norm. The fiddle I'm basing this off can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/hxRPQ/22/

The HTML I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 33</title>
    <link href="base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="./jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./jquery/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="iFCont">
        <iframe src="./HTMLFiles/07.html" class="iF"  id="if1" style="left: 5px;"></iframe>
        <iframe src="./HTMLFiles/08.html" class="iF2" id="if2" style="left: 1010px;"></iframe>
        <iframe src="./HTMLFiles/09.html" class="iF2" id="if3" style="left: 2015px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The js file:

```
function scroll()
{
    var if1 = $("if1");
    var ofs = if1.offset();
    var posX = ofs.top - $(window).scrollTop();
    var posY = ofs.left - $(window).scrollLeft();
    $(".output").text("top:" + posY + ", left:" + posX);
}

$(document).ready(function a()
{
    $(window).scroll(scroll);
});
```

and my CSS for reference:

```
body
{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.iF
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1350px;
    position: absolute;
}
.iF2
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1350px;
    position: absolute;
}
.iFCont
{
    display: inline-block !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
.output
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your selector:

```
var if1 = $("if1");   // Look for 'if1' tag
```

Should be:

```
var if1 = $("#if1");  // Look for an element with 'if1' id
```

Comment: Thanks for this, a colleague just pointed this out to me as well. Still new to all this jQuery stuff and I'm blind to my own silly mistakes.